# How to discover computers in this setup?

Tags: java, networking, tcp

I have 3 computers, on the same local network. Computer #1 is a TCP server and computers #2 and #3 are TCP Clients.

When the server starts I am trying to find the IP Addresses of all available clients automatically, so I don't need to enter the IP addresses manually.

I have limited networking experience, can someone please list the ways to do the above?

There are at least 2 ways:

1. Send a UDP Broadcast message to every computer on the network from server and clients will reply back their IP. This seems not ideal.
2. Somehow (not sure how) the server set's up a hostname, e.g. "http://localhost//myapp" and clients check every few seconds if the hostname is up and then connect to server. This seems to be implemented in Java RMI.

I am trying to archive my goal using the Java API if possible and avoid writing much code.

Comment: You could alternatively use mDNS which is a zero-configuration networking protocol to announce and discover registered services across a local network. I haven't used this in Java but [here's a Java library](https://github.com/posicks/mdnsjava) that you could check out

Comment: TCP doesn't have clients or servers. TCP creates peer connections. The client/server model is an application-layer concept. Broadcasts interrupt every host on a LAN, so that is a really bad idea. Multicast is designed to only interrupt the hosts which subscribe to the multicast group, so that is a better way.

Comment: @ev0lution Thanks, I will check it out but I would prefer Java API.

Comment: @Ron Maupin Thanks a lot! I understand the basics. Performance is not an issue at this point. Robustness and simplicity of code is what matters most. Can I have your 2 cents regarding the hostname please?

Comment: Regarding the hostname, can someone please explain how this is implemented: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/Naming.html

Comment: Why don't you try the more obvious and common way, to let the clients discover the server when a user is ready to use the client? You can let the user enter the hostname of the server or use broadcast to discover - it's much less of a problem when it happens on-demand only.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt The server need to know all clients before it starts working.

Comment: Why does it need that?

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt The server is receiving work to do. Then this work is shared among other computers who report back to the server. Maybe it's incorrect to call them "clients".

Comment: What's wrong with a UDP multicast packet?  That's how things like uPNP devices find themselves.

Comment: @Duston Nothing is wrong with broadcast but maybe some firewalls will cause problems in some configurations? I would like to understand how hostnames can be done and the pro/con of each method.

Comment: Host names are controlled by DNS, and they must be registered in the DNS server(s) that the client hosts use. Remember that host names are really only for humans, and the hosts really only connect by IP address. A logical way to do this is for all the hosts to subscribe to a specific multicast group, and announcements such as, "I am the server!" can go out over multicast. Only the hosts wanting to participate by subscribing to the multicast group will get the announcements.